# TimePickerDialog displaying time in 12 hour format

Tags: java, android, timepickerdialog

I followed a short YouTube tutorial about TimePickerDialog. Since the video is short, it does not show how to display selected time in a 12-hour format. I want to know how to display it to 12-hour format with PM and AM at the side of the selected time.

This is the code I followed from YT:

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            int hour = selectedHour;
            int minute = selectedMinute;
            String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
            electionsText.setText("Registrations Will End On:\n" + date + "\n@ " + time);
        }
    };

    int style = AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT;

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, style, onTimeSetListener, hour, minute, false);

    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
    timePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm a");
    String currentTime = simpleDateFormat.format(c.getTime());
    dateTimeSharedViewModel.setTime(currentTime);
}
```

Comment: This code is not directly linked to my code but the logic using `SimpleDateFormat` in your code, answered my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Use the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy classes `Calendar`, `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`.

Generally best to let *java.time* automatically localize rather than hard-code a format.

```
LocalTime
.of( hour , minute )
.format( 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT )
    .withLocale( Locale.US )
)
```

Comment: Oooooh I will definitely try this out, and will update you on my trial

Comment: UPDATE: This is definitely easier to implement and use. I will consider this answer, correct also :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace true instead of false and you're done

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = (timePicker, selectedHour, selectedMinute) -> {
            int hour = selectedHour;
            int minute = selectedMinute;
            String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
            electionsText.setText("Registrations Will End On:\n" + date + "\n@ " + time);
        };


        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, onTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, true);

        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
        timePickerDialog.show();
```